# Lightning applications are not visible in community builder

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-community

I cannot view lightning applications in community builder, however I can see lightning components on there. Is there a limitation or am I missing something?

```
<aura:application implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">

</aura:application>
```

Comment: Its unclear on what your'e asking!

Comment: You are trying to use a *lightning application* in your community builder, whereas you only get *lightning components* available in either community or app builder

Comment: I can see custom components, but not the custom applications in community builder (Napili). @codeyinthecloud

Answer (score 2):

You **cannot** include a *Lightning App* as you are expecting from Community Builder. When using Community Builder, you only get option of including custom components on top of the standard available components.

> The Components panel lists only components that are compatible with the selected page. For example, you can’t add the User Profile Detail component to the Home page.

Lightning App is a collection of components and that it always is expected to run in standalone mode and not within Lightning Experience, or Community or Classic Experience.

For more details you can refer to these links:

- [Edit Community Pages and Components in Community Builder](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=community_builder_edit_pages.htm&type=5)
- [Creating Apps](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/apps_intro.htm)

Comment: +1 from me just added my answer to point him to the resource of aura:app and reinstate on your answer

Comment: Does that mean I cannot use the application events? I don't want to refer child component in the parent when handling events

Comment: No. You can still use application events. A Lightning App and an Application Event are two different things. An App is a collection of components whereas Events are ways to communicate between components. So as long as you are using that within your Component, you can always use it.

Answer (score 1):

**aura:application**: An [app](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_aura_application.htm) is a special top-level component whose markup is in a .app resource.
The markup looks similar to HTML and can contain components as well as a set of supported HTML tags. The **.app resource is a standalone entry point for the app** and enables you to define the overall application layout, style sheets, and global JavaScript includes. It starts with the top-level  tag, which contains optional system attributes. These system attributes tell the framework how to configure the app.

Basically the Lighting apps are their own standalone applications or think of them as alternative to using your flexi pages aka lighting builder pages. To your question you cannot see or use aura:application in community builder.